# Node-Red global.get("camera_url") Reference error: global is not defined

Tags: javascript, iframe, node-red

On a Node-red dashboard, I want to show a camera stream at different flows. The idea behind is to show the camera on each flow.

To show the camera stream, I use an iFrame. Everything works good but I have to give the URL of the stream for each individual iFrame.

So I was thinking about a solution to set the URL in one place and share the value to all the flows. As far as I have understood, I have to use the global context of node-red.

Therefore, I have installed the `node-red-contrib-config` package and placed a config node like this

```html
[
    {
        "id": "3d181192.cf3c5e",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Global data",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "5851290f.6758b8",
        "type": "config",
        "z": "3d181192.cf3c5e",
        "name": "global_camera",
        "properties": [
            {
                "p": "camera_url",
                "pt": "global",
                "to": "http://192.168.178.33:8081",
                "tot": "str"
            }
        ],
        "active": true,
        "x": 157,
        "y": 78,
        "wires": []
    }
]
```

To create the iframe, I tried different things. If I use static URL, it works with template node and UI template node. If I try so get the global value, it never works. I always get

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"

I tried to set the URL as `...src={{global.get("camera_url")}}` and also with different codes like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "739e53d5.fbf2bc",
    "type": "template",
    "z": "3845329d.55847e",
    "name": "",
    "field": "template",
    "fieldType": "msg",
    "format": "handlebars",
    "syntax": "mustache",
    "template": "<iframe id=\"camera\" seamless width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe>\n<script>\n/*(function(scope) {\n    // debugger;\n    var camera_url = global.get('camera_url');\n    window.ifr = document.getElementById(\"camera\");\n    window.ifr.src=camera_url;\n})(scope);\n*/\n  var camera_url = global.get(\"camera_url\");\n    window.ifr = document.getElementById(\"camera\");\n    window.ifr.src=camera_url;\n</script>",
    "output": "str",
    "x": 86,
    "y": 810,
    "wires": [
        [
            "f8f0597d.727d28"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "f8f0597d.727d28",
    "type": "ui_template",
    "z": "3845329d.55847e",
    "group": "ad85611c.fa213",
    "name": "camera",
    "order": 1,
    "width": "6",
    "height": "6",
    "format": "",
    "storeOutMessages": false,
    "fwdInMessages": false,
    "templateScope": "local",
    "x": 90,
    "y": 865,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "77018043.39f11",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "3845329d.55847e",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": "0.3",
    "x": 51,
    "y": 772,
    "wires": [
        [
            "739e53d5.fbf2bc"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "ad85611c.fa213",
    "type": "ui_group",
    "z": "",
    "name": "Serial",
    "tab": "ab06111f.f336",
    "order": 1,
    "disp": true,
    "width": "15"
},
{
    "id": "ab06111f.f336",
    "type": "ui_tab",
    "z": "",
    "name": "Serial Monitor",
    "icon": "dashboard"
}
```

]

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: instead of `global` write `window`. You're still in browser, not in node

Comment: window.get("camera_url") does also not wirk because window does not have a get function. But I've got what you're telling me and was able to solve it. Thank you for this hint.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Adelin for the hint.

Here is my solution. As Adelin explained, I tried to reach global context from browser. This is not possible, it can only be reached on server side code. To overcome this limitation, I use a function node, which reads the global context and put the URL to msg.payload. This message gets forwarded to the template node, which creates the iFrame.

The template node observes the incoming msg and set the src attribute of iframe.
To trigger everything, I added an inject node

```
[
{
    "id": "f8f0597d.727d28",
    "type": "ui_template",
    "z": "3845329d.55847e",
    "group": "ad85611c.fa213",
    "name": "camera",
    "order": 1,
    "width": "6",
    "height": "6",
    "format": "\n<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n           (function(scope){ \n                scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {\n    \n    window.ifr = document.getElementById(\"camera\");\n    window.ifr.src=msg.payload;\n                });\n            })(scope);\n\n</script>\n<iframe id=\"camera\" seamless width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\"></iframe>",
    "storeOutMessages": false,
    "fwdInMessages": false,
    "templateScope": "local",
    "x": 95,
    "y": 973,
    "wires": [
        []
    ]
},
{
    "id": "70c649d2.ea3648",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "3845329d.55847e",
    "name": "get_camera_url",
    "func": "msg.payload = global.get(\"camera_url\");\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 108,
    "y": 926,
    "wires": [
        [
            "f8f0597d.727d28"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "d0e3c1a7.33c8f",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "3845329d.55847e",
    "name": "trigger camera",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "x": 89,
    "y": 873,
    "wires": [
        [
            "70c649d2.ea3648"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "ad85611c.fa213",
    "type": "ui_group",
    "z": "",
    "name": "Serial",
    "tab": "ab06111f.f336",
    "order": 1,
    "disp": true,
    "width": "15"
},
{
    "id": "ab06111f.f336",
    "type": "ui_tab",
    "z": "",
    "name": "Serial Monitor",
    "icon": "dashboard"
}
```

]